# Why is this Plotly graph is hovering Y and X axis?

Tags: python, plotly, data-science, jupyter-lab

I am trying to plot a normal line chart, taking into account the test column. This should plot the total in the Y-axis and the months in the X-axis. But, the output is weird.

This columns "test" is the one that I want to hover. As we can see in the month 33, it says "98301.00"

[image]

But, when I hover that part, it says: (33, 98.301k) I only want to display 98.301

[image]

Comment: 98.310k = 98 301 cant see the issue .... you can divide test by 1000 if you want to display 98.301

Comment: @BenoitdeMenthière The plot and numbers are not wrong. I think he wants to format the numbers into integers without decimal points or the 'k' post-fix.

Comment: Thanks. But, I was asking is when I hover over the graph, only show the Y axis (it could be 98.310k or 98 301)

Comment: This was the answers; hoverinfo= "y" (This allow you to display the info that you only want)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this instead:**

```
hoverinfo= 'none' # Add as go.Scatter parameter
```

**Code:**

```
# Within go.Scatter add parameter hoverinfo= 'none'

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = df['col1'],
        y = df['col2'],
        hoverinfo = 'none'
    )
)
```

- Note this is just one way to do it, there are other ways too.